# How to match beginning of line java

Tags: java, regex

I am completely new to regular expressions in java,

I am reading a file line by line and trying to use `string.matches` for 3 characters and then 10 numbers at the beginning of the line.

In textpad I can do something like:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

How do I convert this in to java regex?

Comment: You could start here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use quantifiers.
So,

`x{n}` means match `n` number of x **exactly**

`x{n,}` matches x `n` to **many** times

`x{n,m}` matches x `n` to `m` times..

So,your regex would be

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}\\d{10}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's same, but optimized:

```
"^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{10}"
```

or equal one

```
"^[A-Z]{3}\\d{10}"
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the method string.startsWith(). Then the first '^' is not needed.

Comment: ``startsWith()`` does not work with regular expressions and is thus useless in this case.